# Automorphisms of cohomology ring of a topological spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a based ($p$-local)  CW-complex. $H^i(X)$ be the reduced $i$-th cohomology group of $X$, $H^\ast(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})=\oplus_{i\geq 1} H^i(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_m]$, where $x_i$ are cohomology classes of dimension $k_i(i.e., x_i\in H^{k_i}(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})), ~k_1\leq \cdots\leq k_m$. If a self-map $f\colon X\to X$ induces an automorphism $f^\ast\colon H^i(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\to H^i(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ for $i\leq k_m$, then is $f^\ast\colon H^\ast(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\to H^\ast(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ a ring automorphism ?

Comment: I trie to inductively prove  that $f^\ast\colon H^\ast(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\to H^\ast(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is an automorphism (on $m$), but I cannot convince myself.

Answer (score 2):

The map is surjective since all generators are in the image. Since each grading is a finite set this implies that it is bijective, and so it is an automorphism.